# Rails 4: Surpress after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I'm trying to do the equivalent of Rails 3's `Model.send(:create_without_callbacks)` in Rails 4, but cannot find a working means of doing so.

A common method in Rails 3 of calling `.skip_callback()` and `.set_callback()` doesn't work here, as `.set_callback()` doesn't exist in Rails 4.

Comment: `skip_callback` and `set_callback` should work in rails 4  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, then you can achieve that with a lambda definition, like this:

```
after_create :your_method, :if => lambda{ --your true/false set of conditions-- }
```